# Help recreating Sci-Fi PBR texture

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

I'm relatively new to blender and I'm trying to replicate this [procedural texture:](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/nQlJZ9)
[image]

The artist was kind enough to share their node setup on the website, so I have tried copying it, but my texture doesn't look quite the same. Here is the artists node setup:[image]

And here is my node setup: [image]

As you can see my texture doesn't really look like the reference image.
If anyone knows what I've done wrong or a way to make it look more like the reference image it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my [image] .blend file if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an answer, per se, however I have too much to write to fit in a comment box.

The first thing I can see is that the material uses displacement. Displacement requires that you both use Cycles render engine, and have a heavily (and I mean *heavily* ) subdivided mesh. I don't know about your number of subdivisions, but I can see from your image that you are viewing through the *shading* tab, which uses *Material Preview* mode by default, which uses a render engine more similar to eevee. Press Z in the 3D viewport and select "Rendered" from the pie menu (assuming you are using Cycles). You will also have to enable "Bump And Displace" (because you are using Bump too) in the material settings (shown below):

[image: Displace]

EDIT - here's what your file looks like with the settings/changes I mentioned. As you can see, it's closer, but you will still have some correction to do with the rest. To make the displacement more accurate, I added a Subdivision Surface Modifier to the mesh (to increase the number of subdivisions and give more detail - do not go higher than 3 levels if you use it or you will crash your file).

[image: Displace2]

Comment: For the record, if you want to make futuristic tech and stuff like that, but want to go a _bit_ easier than procedural textures, you could try creating Displacement textures - there's a free program called JSPlacement which specializes in making maps like that that can be used easily in blender. Here's one example video showing how to make a spaceship using it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ClYNCvE8sk

Comment: Mess with the midlevel of the displacement node to fill out the sphere again

Comment: Thanks, it's working now!